# Merging speed limit from OpenStreetMap with Ordnance Survey data using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap, road, ordnance-survey

I am working with the Ordnance Survey ITN layer for the UK road network in ArcGIS. Unfortunately, whilst it has many attributes, speed limits is not one of them.

I have produced roughly accurate speed limits based on the attributes provided, i.e.

DescTerm = A Road

Nature = Single Carriageway

Speed would equal 60mph.

Whilst this is roughly right, in reality, many roads have reduced speed limits through towns etc. OpenStreetMap data has speed limits within it and I would like to bring these across to the ITN layer data. The roads roughly line up but are not always perfect.

I envisage that ArcGIS would somehow snap one road to another and then, with code, bring across the appropriate attributes.

I am looking for some assistance in where to begin with this.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Thank you. Whilst I would do this, my searches have been limited. I am probably being too narrow but even a hint on where to begin would be useful.

Comment: I would start by looking at the ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap but what you need to do will be a multi-step process that you will need to work through one step at a time.

Comment: Thanks. I already have the data within ArcGIS from both sources. I am looking for a clue I guess on where to begin on how to determine that road X/OS is the same as road X/OSM and then pass an attribute across. I realise it will need to be a multi-step process within ArcGIS but I'm not certain on what tools would be best to look into?

Comment: you can workout the speed limit based on the classification and RRI information that is in the ITN MasterMap data from Ordnance Survey and use ArcGIS network analysis to build the cost distance/time. Have done this in the past.

Comment: Yes, this would provide a generic limit. It doesn't provide a completely accurate picture and what I am looking to do requires very accurate times. As an interim, I have done exactly as said and created speeds against each item based on that information.

Comment: I have updated the question as on reflection I see it was quite weak. Hopefully this makes it clearer.

Comment: I think you are looking to conflate the roads? http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/an-overview-of-the-conflation-toolset.htm

Comment: MapMerger might be of interest http://mapmerger.com/attribute-transfer/